# Combining similar data from three different sources into one row for each client,

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-transfer, data-integrity

To start off, I don't really use Excel, but I was given this task.

We are integrating two stores (CRUNCH and FRESH) into our MAIN system, each with their own client formatting. Many clients are shared between all three stores, but the goal is to condense the data into one row, populating data in the necessary column.

[image: Example data set]

In the Example Data set, Apple Candy is the customer and there are three entries from different origins. The customer name is formatted differently in each row and there is a second location. Columns H-J are specific to their origin.

The Goal is to condense all the data for one customer and keep it on one row. So all Apple Candy customer data would be limited to row 2, and the client numbers from each origin would populate into row 2. IF the address is different, a second entry could be added. The ideal scenario would look like this desired data set

[image: Desired data set]

The real data set has +9000 rows and 45 columns. What is the easiest and quickest way to complete this task.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an ideal job for Power Query (Data ribbon > Get and Transform group of commands). Load the data into the Power Query editor, then sort by whatever criterion you need to get the data into a consecutive order, then fill down the blank cells from the row above (there is a ribbon command for that in Power Quer), and then delete rows where specified columns have duplicates.

It can all be done with a few clicks and no programming or writing formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheets are not ideal tools for large queries, or for integrating data from multiple sources. A better tool is a relational database, such as free [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com) and [Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org), or commercial tools such as [Oracle Database](https://www.oracle.com/database/).

It is simpler, in the long run, to use [Structured Query Language (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) to create tables, such as Customer, Contacts, Sales (perhaps with columns for Crunch and for Fresh), etc., to import data from those spreadsheets, and to update and query those tables for future use.

Unless this is just an educational assignment to learn Excel, you'll find a database is a better tool.